# Why in creating validation in Formik I have an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implement forms using the "Formik" library

I have this code:

```
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import FInput from './FInput/FInput';

const Form = () => {
    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange} = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
          username: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          confirm_password: '',
      },
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape( schema: {
          username: yup.string()                            // the error here
           .required('This field is required'),
          email: yup.string()
           .required('This field is required')
           .email('This field is required'),
          password: yup.string()
           .required('This field is required')
           .min(6, 'This password is too short')
           .max(30, 'This passwors is too long'),
        confirm_password: yup.string()
        .oneOf([yup.ref(key:'password'), null])
        .required('This field is required'),                                    
      }),
      onSubmit: (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
      },    
    });
    
   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <FInput
         label="username"
         id="username" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'username',
           value: values.username,
           onChange: handleChange,
       }}
       />
      <FInput
         label="email"
         id="email" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'email',
           value: values.email,
           onChange: handleChange,
           type: 'email',
       }}
       />
       <FInput
         label="password"
         id="password" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'password',
           value: values.password,
           onChange: handleChange,
           type:'password',
       }}
       />
       <FInput
         label="Confirm password"
         id="confirm_password" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'confirm_password',
           value: values.confirm_password,
           onChange: handleChange,
           type:'password',
       }}
       />
       <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
   </form>
   );
};

export default Form;
```

I have error:

> Line 18:25:  Parsing error: Unexpected reserved type string
>
> 18 |           username: yup.string()

By the way, `username` is not highlighted in color in text editor.
How to fix error? I have looked at the code many times and cannot understand what caused the error.Please help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object.shape` API takes as an argument an object with fields in them.

[Docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema)

The Yup definition for Formik has to be:

```
validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string()                            
           .required('This field is required'),
  email: yup.string()
           .required('This field is required')
           .email('This field is required'),
  password: yup.string()
           .required('This field is required')
           .min(6, 'This password is too short')
           .max(30, 'This passwors is too long'),
  confirm_password: yup.string()
        .oneOf([yup.ref(key:'password'), null])
        .required('This field is required'),   
})
```